# сделать такую кнопку при нажатии на котороюю под ней будет выскакивать другие кнопки или тексты java

Tags: java, android

Я начинающий android java разработчик и недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой что мне надо сделать такую кнопку при нажатии на котороюю под ней будет выскакивать другие кнопки или тексты вопрос состоит в том что я не знаю как это реализовать а помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner Начинающий разработчик мог бы начать с чтения какой-нибудь простой книжки. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-you-want-to-become-an-android-developer-read-these-books-914cdf4b5347/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довольно сложно дать определенный ответ используя только информацию из вопроса. Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Динамически создавать кнопки или текстовые поля.
2. Показывать/скрывать кнопки/текстовые поля которые указаны в xml

Первый вариант подразумевает что у вас динамическое кол-во кнопок и текстовых полей. Вот [пример](https://www.journaldev.com/19838/android-button#create-button-programmatically) программного создания кнопки:

```
Button programmaticButton = new Button(this);
programmaticButton.setId(R.id.button2);
programmaticButton.setText("CREATED PROGRAMMATICALLY");
programmaticButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Programmatic Button is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});

LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
linearLayout.addView(programmaticButton);
```

[подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710200/android-programmatically-adding-buttons-to-a-layout) на enSO.

Второй вариант подразумевает что у вас фиксированное кол-во кнопок/текстовых полей и поэтому вы можете заранее их указать в xml и просто потом показывать/скрывать. По поводу "выскакивания" - это нужно делать использую анимацию. Вот есть [примеры](https://www.journaldev.com/9481/android-animation-example#fade-in-animation) анимации. И [вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation) использования анимации:

```
view.animate()
    .translationY(0)
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

[туториал](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm) по анимированию

Comment: Я недавно узнал ,что это называется Accardeon